# Are "what technology does FooBarApp use?" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

See title.

- If FooBarApp is open-source, is such  a question off-topic because the question is answered by an off-site resource (the source code itself)?
- If FooBarApp is closed-source, is such  a question off-topic because the answer is either speculation, non-public information, or both?

Example that raised this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25940696/139010 (10k+ users only):

[image]

That question might not be a particularly good example, as it seems to be something of a library-recommendation question in disguise.

Comment: Not sure how it would be on topic unless the post was asking how to use the technology, will knowing that FooBarApp is using technology  x help improve people's programming knowledge/skill?

Comment: @JoeW obviously not. My main motivation for asking this question is to establish something that I can link to when closing such questions in the future, since there's no existing off-topic reason that covers this AFAICS.

Comment: They can be very constructive questions.  It just doesn't happen very often.  As always, vote for the specific question, not the category.

Comment: @HansPassant any chance you have an example on hand?

Comment: I never ever have anything on hand but an opinion.  Good examples take much longer.

Comment: I don't understand the differentiation between open source or closed source?  Closed source software doesn't often hide implementation, or possible implementation details.  For instance, a lot of games implement 3D with OpenGL.  You know because OpenGL support is required.  For web-based applications, there is usually only one good way to do something, and you can look at the network traffic or minified JS to see it.

Comment: I had a similar question pop up not too long ago, but wasn't sure what to do with it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313473/what-language-is-this-bootcamp-compass-and-sass.  But since its not under a popular tag it will never accumulate enough votes to close.

Comment: Another related example: [What really happens on price comparison websites?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947368/what-really-happens-on-price-comparison-websites). I moved to close. I hope I made the right choice.

Answer (score -25):

IMHO these questions can be valid.

Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287029/what-framework-is-used-to-enable-cross-language-communication-in-mozilla-platfor) (closed as too broad)

Comment: This is a horribly vague answer with a pretty bad example. That question was closed because it asked a horribly broad question about how something worked. The original question there did **not** just ask which framework Mozilla used - it essentially asks how that framework (which Mozilla uses) works. In fact, the body of the question still asks that because you only altered the title.