# At what point (if ever) is a fact-based question about the behaviour of closed-source software off-topic / not a good fit for SO?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently came across [What is VSCode remote doing during the "Downloading with wget" step?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75999646/11107541). [VS Code's remote extensions are closed-source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release). This question in particular might be answerable by logging the syscalls made on the remote end, or by sniffing packets (I don't know enough about network layers and package sniffing to know if that's possible for TLS communications ([related wireshark docs](https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS#tls-decryption), which I don't understand)).

It prompted me to wonder if there's any point at which a question about the workings of a piece of closed-source programming-related software is not a good fit for this site.

I presume that a large class of such questions are answerable with reference to facts by someone with the right reverse-engineering / debugging / probing know-how...

If a question solicits fact-based answers to a question about a piece of programming-related software, does that necessarily make it on-topic / a good fit for this site- regardless of how much technical expertise it would take to find that answer in the case of the software being closed-source?

And if someone with that know-how comes along and knows that the question is impossible to answer, what should they do? And what about someone who doesn't have that know-how, but has suspicions that it might not be answerable? Just leave it?

I'm not talking about questions that bleed into the areas of opinions such as "why did the designers of the software choose to design their software this way". I've also heard of something called "speculation-based questions", but I think that doesn't apply here, since  in theory (I don't have any examples on hand) some of the type of question in question here can be answered without speculation.

Related:

- [Questions about debugging/reverse-engineering binaries](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299100/11107541) (does this answer this question? What if the question on the main site is phrased without *asking* for someone to debug / reverse-engineer / probe the software? [rene's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299102/11107541) there doesn't give a clear statement on whether such a question is on-topic, though it does seem to say that such a question is not a good fit for this site if the question post doesn't provide relevant disassembly (or presumably other debugging info such as packet traces))
- [Would a question about how Git works internally be on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298145/11107541) (but git is open-source. [@Bill the Lizard's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298146/11107541) touches on closed-source a little bit, but only a little bit)
- [Are "what technology does FooBarApp use?" questions on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271739/11107541) (closed as a dup of [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/11107541), which I'm not sure if my question falls under the category of)
- [What should be done with questions that ask for nonexistent resources?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258551/11107541) (about informational resources such as documentation)

Comment: My vague thought is that if it's not, like, "why does X do Y?" or *completely* unanswerable (would require debugging a closed-source SaaS app where you don't even have the binaries or any way whatsoever to reverse engineer the behavior), and it's otherwise a question that would be on-topic for an application where the source _is_ available, then it's probably fine.

Comment: Regarding one small part of this: _And if someone with that know-how comes along and knows that the question is impossible to answer,_ well, they could provide an answer to that effect,  preferably with supporting evidence

Comment: FWIW, not every question that is asked will get an answer. A question can be perfectly on-topic here at Stack Overflow and simply not be seen by anyone who knows the answer... if those who view it don't deem it a particularly good or noteworthy question, it will be deleted by the Roomba process after a few months or a year (depending on various criteria). However, if even one other person finds value in the question, they can upvote it, which will prevent it from being automatically deleted indefinitely. In those cases, a question may be seen by someone who knows the answer _years_ later.

Comment: The question referenced could have been asked better, but it's common for me to troubleshoot tools when their behavior is preventing me from working with them. If VS Code isn't fetching an resource, I'm not going to find a new IDE or do without the resource. I'm going to try to fix the problem, even if it's caused by internal code, even if it requires me learning a bit about an internal workflow.

Comment: Counterintuitively, my experience with questions of the form _"why did the designers of the software choose to design their software this way"_, is that they do not _"bleed into the areas of opinions"_ because the only people who can answer such questions are those who actually designed the software, or are SMEs. At least for Java, the language designers regularly post authoritative answers to _"why"_ questions on SO, and I'm guessing that is probably true for other software as well.

Comment: @skomisa huh. I didn't know that about the Java tag (I don't monitor it). I guess I got that impression about these sorts of question because I've seem my share of questions like in the C++ tag like "why isn't C++ like X" get closed for reasons of "go ask the committee" or "probably nobody thought of that. go write a proposal" (something along those lines- memory a little foggy).

Comment: @user Based on your description that sounds like a separate problem: some folks just love finding any excuse to vote to close questions. Perhaps that is sometimes due to the misperception that _"Why...?"_ questions necessarily invite opinions, even though that is not the case. See [Is asking "why" on language specifications still considered as "primarily opinion-based" if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323334/2985643) for an interesting discussion on that. The most upvoted answer came from someone who has written many _"Why...?"_ answers on C#.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I don't think we should preemptively reject questions about closed-source software.

I see no problem in allowing such questions. It's not like they're flooding the review queues or anything, it's just that they are not answerable by *everyone*. But that has never been a prerequisite.

Such a question is about software commonly used by developers, it is about software-developing software, therefore it's just on-topic.

Comment: If in your last paragraph saying "_Such a question is about software commonly used by developers_", you're referring specifically to [the example question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75999646/11107541) I showed, yes, [VS Code questions are in general allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337024/11107541).

Comment: Oh you wouldn't believe the amount of Metizens who only want questions about debugging code on main, so I find that distinction necessary in my answer (s) about scope.

Comment: IIRC, there are people who are denying VS Code is an IDE (they don't understand what "integrated" means), and are calling it a text editor, and therefore a general-purpose tool and thus off-topic. I have edited my answer to remove my opinion though, thanks.

Comment: @CodeCaster worth noting that even if VSCode is not an IDE it would still be considered a tool primarily used by programmers. Notepad++ is on-topic for SO and that's *most definitely* a text editor, rather than IDE.

Comment: @VLAZ It's also perhaps worth noting that, at least for some languages, there are plugins available for Notepad++'s plugin market that enable to to build and execute code, making it a fully-fledged IDE. I have never seen anyone try to argue VS Code is not an IDE though. That's... pretty silly.

Comment: @TylerH it's been said by people who don't think plugins make something an integrated development environment. They wouldn't understand/agree that "integrated" just means that you don't have to switch from editor to compiler to debugger while developing.

Comment: @CodeCaster But you don't have to use plugins to do that in VS Code. It's an IDE "out of the box". Those people are simply _wrong_.

Comment: @TylerH being wrong has never stopped people from close-voting. And you know as well as I how hard it is to get a question you believe to be legitimate to be reopened. That being said, you don't get, like, C# support out of the box, you have to install plugins for about every language/framework/runtime.

Comment: *"I have never seen anyone try to argue VS Code is not an IDE though."* - I've definitely said in the past (erroneously I'm sure) that VSCode is not an IDE, when compared to something like Visual Studio, or PHPStorm, etc. But the reason I say (said ) that is that I couldn't run or debug PHP programs in VSCode "out of the box" like PHPStorm does. Extensions definitely make that possible though, so it can be used as an IDE, just like Notepad++ or Sublime Text, etc. Text Editor vs IDE is always going to have some grey area/overlap (IMO anyway), so "on-topic-ness" does get questioned sometimes.

Comment: @TylerH [Have a shoddy SEDE query (and bunch of false positives)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1738088/vs-code-is-not-an-ide-comments)

Comment: @CodeCaster I want primarily how-to questions on main, not "debugging" questions (by the time the expected effort has been put in to create a MRE and identify the source of a problem, it is no longer what I consider a debugging question). However, I continue to disagree strongly with SO's policy to allow questions about using the tools. I also think, for example, cooking.SE shouldn't host questions about the physical maintenance and repair of kitchen appliances (AFAIK, they *don't*, and are better off for it).

Answer (score 8):

Closed vs. Open source is not black and white distinction. Nor does Open Source mean "Open Book". Behavior becomes harder to understand and assess as even open-source systems age, making SO important for users of such systems. Even new complex, open, and well documented systems benefit from interpretation (git, looking at you). Very often this community has descriptions of behavior and important strategies for common goals, not found elsewhere.

I would offer based on this reasoning that there is therefore *no reason to limit SO answers based on any license or interpretation of a license*. Said another way, discussions of user concerns are [orthogonal](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/orthogonal) to licensing and its concerns.

Answer (score 0):

If answering the question would require reverse engineering, it's not reasonably scoped (Needs More Focus).

If it's about the design decisions made by the software, then that's purely speculative unless they're documented somewhere.

However, if it's about the public interface to software that is itself particular to programming (say, a closed-source VCS, or an IDE) then it is established to be on topic (even if I personally disagree with the wisdom of the policy).

Comment: Just because an answer requires reverse engineering doesn't mean it isn't focused or reasonably scoped. As a contrived example, a question about the programmatic delay between network calls in a piece of closed-source software would be relatively straightforward to "reverse engineer" by analysing network traffic. Although I agree with your overall sentiment, I think there are important caveats to a statement like "reverse engineering question" == "not reasonably scoped question".